# convert dropdwn list to radio buttons on configurable product page

Tags: magento2.3, configurable-product

Is there anyway to convert dropdown list to radio buttons in a configurable page please!
I'm using Magento 2.3
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The input type of any attribute that is used for a product variation must be one of the following:

```
Dropdown
Visual Swatch
Text Swatch
```

So radio button is not supported for configurable product attribute at all.

Reference: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html

Hope it will help.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you, it hepls a lot